# How to convert to nested json from dataframe

Tags: r, json, d3.js

I am trying to render some `d3` graphs in r. I'd like to maintain control over the js so all I want to do is convert my data into a format that the js will take (rather than use a package that will do everything for me)

I dont seem to be able to get the nesting I am looking for using the following:

```
myfile<-data.frame(paste0(iris$Species,".",row.names(iris)),iris$Sepal.Length*100,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        names(myfile)<-c("id","value")
        mydata<-jsonlite::toJSON(myfile,pretty=TRUE)
```

which gives me

```
{
   "id": "Species.virginica.149",
    "value": 620
  },
  {
    "id": "Species.virginica.150",
    "value": 590
  }
```

whereas i would like the species to be the parent and number after the species to be the child with the value being the value of that child.

In the end I want to create a treemap like [this one](https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/articles/gallery/treemap/) so I suppose i am looking for a way to get data in the format required by this treemap (ie the same format as [here](https://github.com/rstudio/r2d3/blob/master/vignettes/gallery/treemap/flare.json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a nested json you have to nest your dataframe, e.g. using `tidyr::nest`. Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

myfile <- iris %>%
  mutate(id = row.names(iris)) %>% 
  select(id, Species, value = Sepal.Length) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>% 
  rename(children = data)

mydata <- jsonlite::toJSON(myfile, pretty = TRUE)
mydata
#> [
#>   {
#>     "Species": "setosa",
#>     "children": [
#>       {
#>         "id": "1",
#>         "value": 5.1
#>       },
#>       {
#>         "id": "2",
#>         "value": 4.9
#>       },
#>       {
#>         "id": "3",
#>         "value": 4.7
#>       },

#> ...
#> ]
```